# How to override bootstrap responsive nav-btn

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, button, responsive-design, nav

[image]

Hi I am trying to override the css for the bootstrap nav btn in my css, I want to change the colour and thickness of the 3 white lins but I have had trouble finding where to change I know it is to do with the span icon-bar but not sure where in the css.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```
.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle .icon-bar {
  width: 20px;
  height: 4px;
  background-color: #cc0000;
  display: block;
}
```

Demo: http://bootply.com/79822

Answer (score 0):

The class you are looking for is "icon-bar"

This controls the bars.

Look for the below code in the css file:

```
.navbar .btn-navbar .icon-bar {
  display: block;
  width: 18px;
  height: 2px;
  background-color: #f5f5f5;
  -webkit-border-radius: 1px;
     -moz-border-radius: 1px;
          border-radius: 1px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
     -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
          box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
}
```

Modify this as you see fit.

Good luck!

Comment: How can I change the thickness of the 3 bars, I changed the height value but had no luck.

Comment: change the height: 2px; this can be any number you like... eg, height: 4px;

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for me it just adds more space inbetween the lines

Comment: Can you show an example? This works on the current version of bootstrap